# Is there any open source project or free API providing crypto wallets for exchanges?

Tags: open-source, api, cryptocurrency

I am interested to know, if I want to make a facility to my website users to be able to pay/buy with crypto currencies, also to gain the ability to send/receive crypto currencies together (something like what crypto exchanges do), what is the solution for that?

As my understanding, crypto exchanges like Coinbase or Binance create a wallet for each user and each currency, and users use their wallets created by the exchange to transfer currencies between themselves. If this is correct, how do they create these wallets for their customers? Are there any APIs for doing that or their create their own wallets, etc?